# UIScrollView doesn't always scroll driving me crazy

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a UIScrollView with 2 UIImageViews inside. The images have a height of about 2330 pixels if you add them up.

In the Storyboard (iPad) I set the the UIScrollView size to width 768 and height to 1024.

Inside the viewDidLoad of the ViewController I set the contentsize of the UIScrollView programmatically like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

    [self.introScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    self.introScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(768,4500);

}
```

with a height of 4500 pixels which is more than enough for both images to fit. 
The funny thing is that it worked once and then stopped working again!!! How is it possible that it works and then stops again. It is not logical. It must a bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off AutoLayout in the IB for the UIScrollView which automatically deleted the constraints for the UIImageViews and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Sorry I was away all day so I couldn't help you.  Glad that you got to working (though I'm not sure what could have been done to the subviews to make a difference).  You can mark your own answer correct since it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First most common cause is contentSize, which you've handled.

Second most common cause is the outlet isn't set `NSLog(@"%@",self.introScrollView);` should not be nil.  If it is, then you're not ever getting the chance to set contentSize.

A distant third is userInteractionEnabled on the scroll view has been set to NO in IB or elsewhere.

A distant fourth is a gestureRecognizer on a parent or overlapping sibling is stealing the gestures.

I'd wager on #2 in this case.

Comment: I've checked #2 and outputs in the console:

Comment: <UIScrollView: 0x17540f00; frame = (0 0; 768 5000); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17553eb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1754e8a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: also checked #3 and user interaction enabled is ticked in IB. I don't use any gestureRecognizer which dismisses #4.

Comment: I've tried deleting the app from the iPad that I'm testing on and adding it again. Didn't help either. Thank you for your time danh!

Comment: OK now it gives me <UIScrollView: 0x17e753c0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17e7d6c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17e74d80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: which means that it ignores my code and still sets it to 1024 pixels high from the IB settings